# OpenCV Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv, cocoapods

I am currently using OpenCV in a Swift project. I have no experience using the library and I have some questions.

1. Is it possible to use Swift to directly communicate with the OpenCV library?

If not:

2. I have used Cocoa Pods to download the OpenCV framework. Do I still need to write an Objective-C++ wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, OpenCV requires you to use Objective-C++
2. Yes you do, you can write your interface and native code in swift but you still have to bridge it with whatever you wanna do in OpenCV.